# Return a list of rows with my daily capital from a table with cash inflows?

Tags: sql

I have a database that holds a list of inflows of cash:

```
Amount Date
100    11/4/2013
150    12/4/2013
50     12/4/2013
240    13/4/2013
```

I need to get a list of rows with my capitalization (the sum of all rows to that date) for each day.

In this case the result should be:

```
Capital Date
100     11/4/2013
300     12/4/2013
540     13/4/2013
```

I would normally append what I am trying but I have no idea how to do this. Could someone tell me how can this be done on SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T2.date, SUM(T1.Amount) AS SUM FROM SomeTable T1
INNER JOIN SomeTable T2 ON T1.date <=T2.date
GROUP BY T2.date
```